# SyntaxError unexpected token <

Tags: json, jqgrid

I've been struggling 2 weeks to find the answer of these problem without any success. I'm using phpgrid from phpgrid.com, this error is not happen in offline but when i upload to server this problme came up. Every time i fill a form with upload image field, this error popup.

Bellow is the response i copied from chrome developer tools.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->


<script>
//<![CDATA[
var lastSel;
var phpGrid_products;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    phpGrid_products = jQuery("#products").jqGrid({
        url:"/data.php?dt=json&gn=products",
        datatype:"json",
        mtype:"GET",
        colNames:["product_id","Type","Serial number","Product name","Product specification","End user","Acceptance date","Warranty expire date","Latest Status","Photo"],  colModel:[
            {"name":"product_id","index":"product_id","hidden":true,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{"size":"30"},   "editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false,"number":true}
            },
            {"name":"type","index":"type","hidden":false,"width":70,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{"size":"30"},"editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}
            },
            {"name":"serial_number","index":"serial_number","hidden":false,"width":100,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{"size":"30"},"editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}
            },
            {"name":"product","index":"product","hidden":false,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{"size":"30"},"editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}
            },
            {"name":"specification","index":"specification","hidden":true,"edittype":"textarea","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{"cols":60,"rows":6,"size":60},"editrules":{"edithidden":true,"required":false}
            },
            {"name":"end_user","index":"end_user","hidden":false,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{"size":"30"},"editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}
            },
            {"name":"acceptance_date","index":"acceptance_date","hidden":false,"width":80,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{
                    "dataInit":function(el){
                        $(el).datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true, 
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
                        });
                        },"size":"30"},
                "editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false,"date":true}
            },
            {"name":"warranty_expire","index":"warranty_expire","hidden":false,"width":80,"edittype":"text","editable":true,
                "editoptions":{
                    "dataInit":function(el){
                        $(el).datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true, 
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
                        });},"size":"30"},
                "editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false,"date":true}
            },
            {"name":"status","index":"status","hidden":false,"width":60,"edittype":"select","editable":true,
                "formatter":"select","stype":"select",
                "searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq"],"value":":All;Closed:Closed;In progress:In progess;Pending:Pending"},
                "editoptions":{"value":"Closed:Closed;In progress:In progess;Pending:Pending"},
                "editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}
            },
            {"name":"picture","index":"picture","hidden":false,"align":"center","edittype":"file","editable":true,
                "formatter":imageFormatter,"unformat":imageUnformatter,
                "editoptions":{"enctype":"multipart/form-data"},
                "editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}
            }
        ],
        pager: "#products_pager1",
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30,50,100],
        sortname:"status",
        sortorder:"Desc",
        viewrecords:true,
        multiselect:false,
        caption:"Product list and latest status",
        altRows:true,
        scrollOffset:22,
        rownumbers:true,
        shrinkToFit:true,
        autowidth:true,
        hiddengrid:false,
        scroll:false,
        height:"100%",
        width:"1000",
        sortable:true,
        loadError:
            function(xhr,status, err) {
                try{
                    jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog(
                        jQuery.jgrid.errors.errcap,
                        "<div style=\"font-size:10px;text-align:left;width:300px;;height:150px;overflow:auto;color:red;\">"+ xhr.responseText +"</div>",
                        jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:"center"
                    });
                }
                catch(e) { alert(xhr.responseText)};
                },
        gridview:true,
        editurl:"/edit.php?dt=json&gn=products",
        ondblClickRow: function(){
            var row_id = $(this).getGridParam("selrow");
            $(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", row_id, {           
                // --------- edit options ---------
                afterShowForm:function(form_id){
                    var grid = $(this);
                    var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                    var file_name = grid.jqGrid("getCell",row_id,"picture");
                    if(file_name=="" || file_name === null){
                        $("#picture").show();
                        $("#_fileLink").text(file_name).hide();
                        $("#_btnFileDelete").hide();
                    }else{
                        $("#_fileLink").attr("href", "images/products/" + file_name).text(file_name).show();
                        $("#_btnFileDelete").show();
                        $("#picture").hide();
                        $("#_btnFileDelete").click(function(){
                            ajaxFileDelete(form_id, row_id);
                            // return true;
                        });
                    }
                },
                onInitializeForm:function(form_id){
                    $('<a href="" id="_fileLink" target="_new"></a>').insertAfter("#picture").hide();
                    $('<button id="_btnFileDelete">Delete</button>').insertAfter("#_fileLink").hide();
                },
                afterSubmit:function(d,a){
                    var grid = $(this);
                    var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                    $("#_products_debug_ajaxresponse").html("<pre>"+d.responseText+"</pre>");
                    success:{
                        ajaxFileUploadEdit(d,a,row_id);
                    }
                        return true;
                },
                jqModal:true,
                checkOnUpdate:false,
                savekey: [true,13],
                width:560,
                height:"100%",
                navkeys: [false,38,40],
                checkOnSubmit : false,
                reloadAfterSubmit:false,
                resize:true,
                closeOnEscape:true,
                closeAfterEdit:true,bottominfo:"* required",
                viewPagerButtons:true,
                beforeShowForm: function(frm) { }
            }); // editGridRow
        }, // ondblClickRow
        loadComplete: function(data){
            if($("#products").getGridParam("reccount") != 0){
                $.each(data.rows,function(i,item){
                    if (item.cell['8'] != null) {
                        if (item.cell[8].substr(-1)==="d") {
                            $("#" + item.id).css("color","#000000");
                            $("#" + item.id).removeClass("ui-widget-content");
                            $("#" + item.id).css("background-color","#ffffff");
                        } 
                    }if (item.cell['8'] != null) {
                        if (item.cell[8].substr(-1)==="s") {
                            $("#" + item.id).css("color","#000000");
                            $("#" + item.id).removeClass("ui-widget-content");
                            $("#" + item.id).css("background-color","#FF3232");
                        }        
                    }if (item.cell['8'] != null) {
                        if (item.cell[8].substr(-1)==="g") {
                            $("#" + item.id).css("color","#000000");
                            $("#" + item.id).removeClass("ui-widget-content");
                            $("#" + item.id).css("background-color","#FFFF80");
                        } 
                    } 
                })
            };                    
        },
        loadtext:"Loading phpGrid ..."
    });
    jQuery("#products").jqGrid("navGrid", "#products_pager1",
    {edit:true,add:true,del:true,view:true,cloneToTop:true,search:false,excel:false}, 
        {           
            // --------- edit options ---------
            afterSubmit:
                function(d,a){
                    var grid = $(this);
                    var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                    $("#_products_debug_ajaxresponse").html("<pre>"+d.responseText+"</pre>");
                    success:{ajaxFileUploadEdit(d,a,row_id);}
                        return true;
                    },   // icon edit options
            afterShowForm:function(form_id){
                    var grid = $(this);
                    var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                    var file_name = grid.jqGrid("getCell",row_id,"picture");
                    if(file_name=="" || file_name === null){
                        $("#picture").show();
                        $("#_fileLink").text(file_name).hide();
                        $("#_btnFileDelete").hide();
                    }else{
                        $("#_fileLink").attr("href", "images/products/" + file_name).text(file_name).show();
                        $("#_btnFileDelete").show();
                        $("#picture").hide();
                        $("#_btnFileDelete").click(function(){
                            ajaxFileDelete(form_id, row_id);
                            // return true;
                        });
                    }
            },
            onInitializeForm:function(form_id){
                $('<a href="" id="_fileLink" target="_new"></a>').insertAfter("#picture").hide();
                $('<button id="_btnFileDelete">Delete</button>').insertAfter("#_fileLink").hide();
            },
            afterSubmit:function(d,a){
                var grid = $(this);
                var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                $("#_products_debug_ajaxresponse").html("<pre>"+d.responseText+"</pre>");
                success:{
                    ajaxFileUploadEdit(d,a,row_id);
                }
                return true;
            },
            jqModal:true,
            checkOnUpdate:false,
            savekey: [true,13],
            width:560,
            height:"100%",
            navkeys: [false,38,40],
            checkOnSubmit : false,
            reloadAfterSubmit:false,
            resize:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            closeAfterEdit:true,
            bottominfo:"* required",
            viewPagerButtons:true,
            beforeShowForm: function(frm) { }
        },
        {           
            // --------- add options ---------
            closeAfterAdd:true,
            bottominfo:"* required",
            viewPagerButtons:true,
            afterComplete: function(response, postdata, formid) {  
                // auto reload
                var $self = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
                }, 50);
            },
            beforeShowForm: function(frm) {
            },
            afterSubmit:function(d,a){
                success:{
                    ajaxFileUploadAdd(d,a);
                }
                return true;
            },
            afterShowForm:function(form_id){
                var grid = $(this);
                var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                var file_name = grid.jqGrid("getCell",row_id,"picture");
                if(file_name=="" || file_name === null){
                    $("#picture").show();
                    $("#_fileLink").text(file_name).hide();
                    $("#_btnFileDelete").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#_fileLink").attr("href", "images/products/" + file_name).text(file_name).show();
                    $("#_btnFileDelete").show();
                    $("#picture").hide();
                    $("#_btnFileDelete").click(function(){
                        ajaxFileDelete(form_id, row_id);
                        // return true;
                    });
                }
            },
            onInitializeForm:function(form_id){
                $('<a href="" id="_fileLink" target="_new"></a>').insertAfter("#picture").hide();
                $('<button id="_btnFileDelete">Delete</button>').insertAfter("#_fileLink").hide();
            },
            afterSubmit:function(d,a){
                var grid = $(this);
                var row_id = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
                $("#_products_debug_ajaxresponse").html("<pre>"+d.responseText+"</pre>");
                success:{
                    ajaxFileUploadEdit(d,a,row_id);
                }
                return true;
            },
            jqModal:true,
            checkOnUpdate:false,
            savekey: [true,13],
            width:560,
            height:"100%",
            navkeys: [false,38,40],
            checkOnSubmit : false,
            reloadAfterSubmit:false,
            resize:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            closeAfterEdit:true,
            bottominfo:"* required",
            viewPagerButtons:true
        },
        { 
            // --------- del options ---------
            reloadAfterSubmit:false,
            jqModal:false,
            bottominfo:"* required",
            closeOnEscape:true
        },
        {
            // --------- view options ---------
            navkeys: [false,38,40],
            height:250,
            jqModal:false,
            resize:true,
            closeOnEscape:true
        },
        {closeOnEscape:true} // search options
    );
    jQuery("#products").jqGrid("navButtonAdd","#products_pager1",
        {caption:"",title:"Toggle inline search", buttonicon :"ui-icon-search",
            onClickButton:function(){
                phpGrid_products[0].toggleToolbar();
            }
        }
    );
    jQuery("#products").jqGrid("filterToolbar", {searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn"});
    phpGrid_products[0].toggleToolbar();
    });
    function getSelRows(){
        var rows = jQuery("#products").jqGrid("getGridParam","selarrrow");
        return rows;
    }
    // cellValue - the original value of the cell
    // options - as set of options, e.g
    // options.rowId - the primary key of the row
    // options.colModel - colModel of the column
    // rowObject - array of cell data for the row, so you can access other cells in the row if needed 
    function imageFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject){
        // Tambahan path folder untuk images karena di master detail tidak berfungsi
        return (cellValue == "" || cellValue === null)? 
            "":"<img src=\""+ cellValue + "\" originalValue=\""+ cellValue +"\" title=\""+ cellValue +"\">";
    }
    // cellValue - the original value of the cell
    // options - as set of options, e.g
    // options.rowId - the primary key of the row
    // options.colModel - colModel of the column
    // cellObject - the HMTL of the cell (td) holding the actual value 
    function imageUnformatter(cellValue, options, cellObject){
        return $(cellObject.html()).attr("originalValue");
    }
    function booleanFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject){
        var op;
        op = $.extend({},options.colModel.formatoptions);
        myCars=new Array();
        //alert(op.No);
        //mycars[cellValue]=  op.boolean.No;
        //mycars[cellValue]=  op.boolean.Yes;
        myCars[op.No]="No";
        myCars[op.Yes]="Yes";
        //alert(options[boolean]);
        return myCars[cellValue];
    }
    function booleanUnformatter(cellValue, options, cellObject){
        var op;
        op = $.extend({},options.colModel.formatoptions);
        //alert(op.No);
        if(cellValue=="No")
            return (op.No);
        else
            return (op.Yes);
        //alert(op.boolean.Yes)
        //return (op.boolean.cellValue);
        //  myCars=new Array();
        //  myCars["No"]='0';
        //  myCars["Yes"]=1;
        //alert(myCars[cellValue]);
        //alert(options.colModel.formatoptions[1]);
        //return myCars[cellValue];
    }
    function ajaxFileUploadEdit(response, postdata, row_id) {
        if ($("#picture").val() == ""){
            return false;
        }
        ajaxFileUpload(row_id, "edit");
    }
    // parse json returend from edit.php for auto generated key, if cannot find, use non-autogen primary key instead
    // auto generated key is probably not 100% reliable
    function ajaxFileUploadAdd(response, postdata) {
        obj= jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        new_row_id = obj.id;
        if(new_row_id == "" || new_row_id == 0){
            new_row_id = postdata.product_id;
        }
        ajaxFileUpload(new_row_id, "add");
    }
    // file upload function used only during add
    function ajaxFileUpload(row_id, oper){
        $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url: "/ajaxfileupload.php?dt=json&gn=products&oper=" +oper+ "&col=picture&folder=",
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: "picture",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: row_id },
            success: function (data, status) {
                $("#products").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
            // displayCrudServerErr(xhr); 
            // does not capture responseText - TODO - needs new ajaxfileupload lib
                if (typeof (data.error) != "undefined") {
                    if (data.error != "") {
                        alert(data.error);
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }else {
                    return alert("Failed to upload!");
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        })
    }
    function ajaxFileDelete(form_id, row_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxfiledelete.php?dt=json&gn=products&col=picture&folder=",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: row_id, file_col: "picture"},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, status) {
                $("#products").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
                $("#_fileLink").hide();
                $("#_btnFileDelete").hide();
                $("#picture").show();
                $("#_products_debug_ajaxresponse").append("<pre>"+data +"</pre>");
            }
        })
    } 
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your live server has PHP installed in Apache module? Check upload_tmp_dir in php.ini. You might need a 3rd parameter in set_col_fileupload.

From 
http://phpgrid.com/example/php-datagrid-ajax-file-upload/

> Since PHP is installed as Apache module in our host server, the 3rd
>   parameter is optional that the physical path is automatically mapped
>   based on 2nd parameter, the base URL.

Remark from 
http://phpgrid.com/documentation/set_col_fileupload/

> - File system only with valid upload_tmp_dir value in php.ini
> - File name column should allow NULL value $physical_path is automaticall obtained if PHP running in Apache module, or MUST be provided as
>     fallback